# Using endswith to read list of files doesn't find extension in list

Tags: python, readfile

I am trying to get my python script to read a text file with a list of file names with extensions and print out when it finds a particular extension (.txt files to be exact). It reads the file and goes through each line (I've tested by putting a simple "print line" after the for statement), but doesn't do anything when it sees ".txt" in the line. To avoid the obvious question, yes I'm positive there are .txt files in the list. Can someone point me in the right direction?

```py
with open ("file_list.txt", "r") as L:
    for line in L:
        if line.endswith(".txt"):
            print ("This has a .txt: " + line)
```

Comment: try `line.strip().endswith(".txt')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each line ends with a new line character `'\n'`, so the test will fail. First use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) or [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) on the line, then test:

```
line.rstrip().endswith('.txt')
#      ^
```

Comment: Yes! This did it. I can't believe I forgot about the new line character. I can't mark this as the answer yet, but I will

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should add the endline sign `\n` at the end of the extension:

```py
with open ("file_list.txt", "r") as L:
    for line in L:
        if line.endswith(".txt\n"):
            print ("This has a .txt: " + line)
```

Comment: And if the line has a whitespace after `'.txt'` as in `line = 'my_test.txt \n'`?

Comment: That'll do it too. Thanks!

Comment: @MosesKoledoye and if the line has a smiley after `.txt'? that's not a normal case.

Comment: Don't get me wrong. The point is that your code is quite easy to break. One could also have `'\r\n'` at the end of the line as with Windows

Comment: @MosesKoledoye well, you are right, and that's the reason I wrote "**I guess**", but this gives the OP a good direction to solve and understand his problem.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye White space at the end of the line might just as well be part of the file name.  It's not likely that it is, but without further information  on the format of the input file, it's impossible to tell what the correct behaviour is.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Well, that could also be the case. So one should *better not **guess** in the face of ambiguity*. Sorry for being pedantic :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`str.rstrip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) to remove trailing whitespaces, such as `\n` or `\r\n`.

```
with open ("file_list.txt", "r") as L:
    for line in L:
        if line.rstrip().endswith(".txt"):
            print ("This has a .txt: " + line)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!